# Rails 5.0.0 jsonapi-parser can't find in any sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers

I got that error when I tried to setup new Rails 5.0.0 application.
When I running 'bundle' command, I'm getting this one:

`Could not find jsonapi-parser-0.1.1.beta2 in any of the sources`

In my Gemfile.lock only 'active_model_serializers' depends from jsonapi witch depend from 'jsonapi-parser'.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You can probably try update active_model_serializers gem
```bundle update active_model_serializers```

Comment: Thanks @rusllonrails, I tried it before, update of jsonapi gem finally fixed it for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think:

`$ bundle update jsonapi`

will solve your issue though.
Works for me.

Comment: I had the same issue with jsonapi in my project bundle update jsonapi did fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need to upgrade your rails to 5.0.0.1, i guess the issue was fixed there. Also it will be a good point for other issues that can appear in future